# Adding string replacements into Required attribute Error Messages

Tags: c#, resource-files

I have the follwing code

```
[Required("SalesChannel", SeenSalesChannelString, 
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = ErrorMessagesErrors.FieldConditionallyRequired)]
```

The field `FieldConditionallyRequired` requires a couple of replacements `{0}` and `{1}`.  How do I provide these?

Comment: What is `Required` attribute?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: oh dear that's not good.